# What is the least privilege needed to update a user's accountEnabled property in Azure AD?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We are using Microsoft Graph API's SDK to try and update the accountEnabled property for users in our Azure AD.

We are using code such as the following:

```
await graphClient.Users[userId]
                .Request()
                .UpdateAsync(
                    new User()
                    {
                        AccountEnabled = false
                    });
```

We receive the following error from Microsoft Graph:

```
"error": {
    "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
    "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."
}
```

In the docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/roles-delegate-by-task), I was able to find under the task "Update user settings" that it requires the role of Global Administrator. In the Azure AD portal, the "Block sign in" (which is equivalent to accountEnabled) is under "Settings".

This seems a bit off to me, but I added my app service principal to the role and it of course worked. (Why wouldn't it work if I just assigned the service principal to Global Administrator. It should now be able to do anything within my Azure AD).

Can anyone confirm that this is the least privilege needed to update a user's accountEnabled property in Azure AD?

Thanks,

Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs for updating a user via Microsoft Graph are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).  You need to request a scope such as User.ReadWrite when you get the access token and consent the application to access that scope/permission.

If you are doing this in a desktop or console app you can do that like this:

```
IPublicClientApplication publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(clientId)
            .Build();
var scopes = new string[] {"User.ReadWrite"};    
InteractiveAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new InteractiveAuthenticationProvider(publicClientApplication, scopes);
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=CS#InteractiveProvider

Comment: I do appreciate the example Darrel, however, I am receiving the token using the ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder with a secret. I am able to update other properties on a user, such as Department, but whenever I try to update AccountEnabled my permissions are insufficient. I have consented the application in the Azure AD portal with scopes User.ReadWriteAll which should be sufficient to update users. Do you know if there are specific permissons required to set the AccountEnabled through graph api? Thanks

Comment: @J.Huntsman I am not aware of separate permissions being necessary.  I just tried using our PowerShell library to update the accountEnabled on a demo tenant and it worked ok.  I was an admin and using delegated access though.